# Перегрузка операторов сложения для двух взаимозависимых классов

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Glass;
class Bottle{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Bottle() { x = 0; }
    Bottle(int m) { x = m; }

    Bottle operator+(const Bottle b);
    Glass operator+(Glass b);

    int get();
    void set(int x) { this->x = x; }
};

int Bottle::get()
{
    //cout << "Result: " << x << endl;  
    return x;
}

Bottle Bottle::operator+(const Bottle b)
{
    Bottle temp;

    temp.x = x + b.x;
    return temp;
}

class Glass{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Glass() { x = 0; }
    Glass(int m) { x = m; }

    Glass operator+(const Glass b);
    Glass operator+(Bottle b);

    int get();
    void set(int x) { this->x = x; }

};

int Glass::get()
{
    //cout << "Result: " << x  << endl;
    return x;
}

Glass Glass::operator+(const Glass b)
{
    Glass temp;

    temp.x = x + b.x;

    return temp;
}

//Складываем m + a.
Glass Glass::operator+(Bottle a)
{
    Glass temp;

    temp.x = x + a.get();
    return temp;
}


int main()
{
    Bottle a(10);
    Glass m(13);
    Glass b(13);

    m = m + a;
    cout << m.get() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Нужно сложить 2 класса, `m = m + a` - так работает, а `m = a + m` так не работает. Как это сделать, не могу понять

Comment: Потрудитесь объяснить, что у Вас не так и в чём нужна помощь. Иначе Ваш вопрос рискует быть замороженным.

Comment: Мне нужно словить 2 класса, m = m + a  так работает, а m = a + mтак не работает. Как это сделать, не могу понять

Comment: Ну перегрузите тогда в Bottle: Glass opeartor+(Glass)

Comment: Так не работает
Bottle Glass::operator+(Glass b)
{
 Bottle temp;

 temp.x = x + b.x;
 return temp;
}

Comment: Наоборот:) Glass Bottle::operator+(Glass b)

Comment: Спасибо за помочь

Comment: Если ответ Вас удовлетворяет, отметьте его решённым: галочка рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще говоря, если просто взять Ваш код, то его исправление элементарно: у Вас просто не определана функция `Bottle::operator+(Glass b)`, поэтому определение оной решит проблему(но она должна быть определена в файле где-то после класса `Glass`):

```
Glass Bottle::operator+(Glass b)
{
    Glass temp;

    temp.set(x + b.get());
    return temp;
}
```

---

Но Вы должны понять, что Ваш код ужасен. Как минимум я предлагаю сделать следующее:

1. `const Glass b` это явно не то, что Вы имели ввиду, нужно передавать константную ссылку, а не константный объект.
2. Вместо добавления операторов сложения с другим объектом в класс, логичнее добавить оператор преобразования одного типа в другой. В сам класс же добавлять лишь сложение с себе подобными.

В результате получится следующий код:

```
class Glass;
class Bottle{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Bottle() { x = 0; }
    Bottle(int m) { x = m; }

    Bottle operator+(const Bottle& b) const
    {
        return Bottle(x + b.x);
    }

    operator Glass() const;

    int get() const { return x; }
    void set(int x) { this->x = x; }
};


class Glass{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Glass() { x = 0; }
    Glass(int m) { x = m; }

    Glass operator+(const Glass& b) const
    {
        return Glass(x + b.x);
    }

    operator Bottle() const
    {
        return Bottle(x);
    }

    int get() const { return x; }
    void set(int x) { this->x = x; }

};

Bottle::operator Glass() const
{
    return Glass(x);
}
```

Он позволяет складывать в обе стороны и проще чем Ваш изначальный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо большое буду разбираться

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил более элегантное решение